# gmail newsletter/promotion tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, get, gmail-api

I am trying to get promotional and newsletter email messages using Gmail API. Currently, I am requesting the Gmail API based on sender, but it is not feasible.  Is there a way to identify an email message as promotions or newsletters, when getting messages using Gmail API?

Is there a meta tag for newsletters or promotional messages?

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thank you!
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tag` you mentioned in the question is called `label` in Gmail API. You can find a list of default labels in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels

I guess you are interested in `CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS`. In that case, you should pass it as a query param called `labelIds[]` of the request, that lists user's messages: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This is what I needed!